# Could not found Wifi?

Tags: wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 in my Lenovo ideapad along with windows 10 .

I could not found how to turn on WiFi even I could not get anything like " No WiFi adapter found " something like that.

Now it has passed a month and I have tried lots of solution from askubuntu , you tube , other forum and even individual blog but nothing working for me . I am getting frustrated with Ubuntu because I have to use internet by USB and some time my Phone also get over charged .

Please help me if any have solution . I have Lenovo with Realtek .

Please help me

Comment: did you try to add a new wifi connection in the connection manager ?

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a rant.

Comment: If you have really tried "lots of solutions," then you already know how to determine your wifi chipset and where to look up those chipsets to learn which are compatible and how to activate them (and which are utterly incompatible.) Also, you have already learned that compatibility is determined by the manufacturer (not  by Ubuntu.)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
 Kernel modules: wl
 
 rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
@chill555